# It's there some function that maps the sample space with the event space?

Tags: probability-theory, set-theory

In the book "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and Its Applications - Richard J. Larsen" it defines the probability of an event in relationship with the sample space as:

$$P(A)=\sum_{s\in A}^{}p(s)$$

[image]

Of course there is a distinction between the function $p$ and $P$. Thus, $p:S\to \mathbb{R}$ and $P:A\to \mathbb{R}$, being A the event space.

**It's there some way to connect the idea of sample elements, events and probabilities?**

What I already try is to use the next definition:

[image]

[image]

The problem with this is that in this specific example, we have that the image of X under p is:

$$p(A_{1})=\{p(s)|s\in A_{1}\}$$

Thus, that would give me:

$$p(A_{1})=\{2/3, 1/6\}$$

That gives me a set and not a real number, I mean I want a sum for that set. I failed to connect the sample space probability with the event space probability. There's a way to do it?

Comment: There should be something wrong... You introduce definition 5.4.1 with $f$... and $f$ is not used later on in your question.

Comment: Just replace it to $p:S \to R$.

Comment: You're confusing two distinct topics. The replacement you mention can't be done here. $f$ is a probability transfer not a probability density.